# Variable increment and for loop in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

forbiddenWords=['for', 'and', 'nor', 'but', 'or', 'yet', 'so', 'not', 'a', 'the', 'an', 'of', 'in', 'to', 'for', 'with', 'on', 'at', 'from', 'by', 'about', 'as']

def clear_screen():
    button2.destroy()
    button3.destroy()
    text.destroy()
    label.destroy()

def main_page():
    var = StringVar()
    global label
    label = Label( root, textvariable=var)
    var.set("Fill in the caps: ")
    label.pack()

    global text
    text = Text(root,font=("Purisa",12))
    text.pack()

    global button
    button=Button(root, text ="Create text with caps.", command =lambda: full_function())
    button.pack()

def clear_and_main():
    clear_screen()
    main_page()

def new_sentences(sentenceList):
    global replaced_indexes
    global replaced_words
    replaced_indexes=[]
    replaced_words=[]
    global newsentences
    newsentences=[]
    for lause in sentenceList:
        import re
        from random import randint
        s6nade_arv=len(lause.split(' '))
        while True:
            asendatava_idx=randint(0,s6nade_arv-1)
            wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  lause).split()
            asendatav_s6na=wordList[asendatava_idx]
            if asendatav_s6na.lower() not in forbiddenWords:
                replaced_indexes.append(asendatava_idx)
                replaced_words.append(asendatav_s6na)
                break
        uus_lause=lause.replace(asendatav_s6na, "______")
        newsentences.append(uus_lause)
    return newsentences

def IntoSentences(paragraph):
    paragraph = paragraph.decode('utf-8').replace(u'\u014c\u0106\u014d','-')
    import nltk.data
    sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    global sentenceList
    sentenceList = sent_detector.tokenize(paragraph.strip())
    return sentenceList

def full_function():
    global button2
    global button3
    IntoSentences(text.get(1.0,END))
    new_sentences(sentenceList)
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    button3=Button(root, text ="Main page", command=lambda: clear_and_main())
    button3.pack()
    button2=Button(root, text ="Answer", command=lambda: get_answers())
    button2.pack()
    button.destroy()
    for i in newsentences:
        text.insert(INSERT, str(i))

def get_answers():
    IntoSentences(text.get(1.0,END))
    i=0
    global correct_answers
    global false_answers
    correct_answers=0
    false_answers=0
    for lause in sentenceList:
        inserted_word=lause[replaced_indexes[i]]
        if inserted_word==replaced_words[i]:
            correct_answers=correct_answers+1
            i=i+1
        elif inserted_word!=replaced_words[i]:
            false_answers=false_answers+1
            i=i+1
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    text.insert(INSERT, "The number of correct answers: ")
    text.insert(END, correct_answers)
    text.insert(INSERT, "\n")
    text.insert(INSERT, "The number of incorrect answers: ")
    text.insert(END, false_answers)


from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
label = Label( root, textvariable=var)
var.set("Fill in the caps: ")
label.pack()

text = Text(root,font=("Purisa",12))
text.pack()

button=Button(root, text ="Create text with caps.", command =lambda: full_function())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

My application works fine but there is one problem. Problem is in function get_answers(). When I insert text and create text with caps and fill in the caps too, then I get text which says me how many correct answers i had and how many false answers either. But it always says it just about last answer. For example: I fill in two caps, first correct,second wrong, program says 0 correct answer, 1 incorrect. As if       correct_answers and false_answers are defined in for loop and get reassigned to 0 every time function runs for one sentence. What should I change in my code to make program show answers right?

Comment: did you check whether it was overwriting it?

Comment: I just understood the for loop runs only once. And thats why it shows such wrong output.

Comment: Why are you using global when you don't access the variables outside of any of the function they are declared in, also  you are using newsentences and sentencelist in functions without using the global keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that key of the problem is related to line

```
inserted_word=lause[replaced_indexes[i]]
```

where `inserted_word` is a single character, not the inserted word. I suppose you wanted to tokenize string into separate words, but this functionallity is missed.

Comment: I already solved that:
`code
wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  lause).split()
inserted_word=wordList[replaced_indexes[i]]
`
But problem is that program takes all my list "sentenceList" as one sentence and I dont know why. Everything works fine in earlier function new_sentences.

Comment: I assume another problem is when you print new text with the underscores. The spaces between sentence dots are missing, so from the sentence list: ["Foo.", "Bar.", "Zuf."] you receive, you generate new set of sentences on the screen, that looks like ``___.___.___.``, that your code treats as one sentence, not three.